# Isar embedded objects not being loaded

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

Seems I'm not able to load embedded objects when loading the parent object from the DB.

Let's say I have the following parent and children classes.

```
@collection
class Email {
  Id? id;
  String? title;
  List<Recepient> recipients = List.empty(growable: true);
}

@embedded
class Recepient {
  String? name;
  String? address;
}
```

If I store it to the Isar database, I can properly see the tree (through Isar Inspector) which includes the embedded objects with all their values. That means the data is properly stored.
The problem is when I try to receive an item of that collection: I get the Email properties properly filled, but the recipients list is always empty.
Reading through Isar documentation, it mentions that embedded objects should be loaded automatically. But I have never found an example with nested objects being Lists. Can that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the List.empty(growable: true). This constructor creates an empty list, but it does not initialize the list with any data. Isar does not automatically load data into lists that are not initialized.
I added a constructor like

```
Email(this.title, this.receipents)
```

and removed the "List.empty(growable: true).
That worked.